# Pandas ignore missing dates to find percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have a dataframe. I am trying to find percentiles of datetimes. I am using the function:

Dataframe:

```
student, attempts, time
student 1,14, 9/3/2019  12:32:32 AM
student 2,2, 9/3/2019  9:37:14 PM
student 3, 5
student 4, 16, 9/5/2019  8:58:14 PM
```

```
studentInfo2 = [14, 4, Timestamp('2019-09-04 00:26:36')]
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time_0001'], errors='coerce')
perc1_first = stats.percentileofscore(data['time'].notnull(), student2Info[2], 'rank')
```

where student2Info[2] holds the datetime for a particular student. When I try and do this I get the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Any ideas on how I can get the percentile to calculate correctly even when there are missing times in the columns?

Comment: Would you provide a small example of the data that I may use to reproduce the exception?

Comment: I added in some data for you. Thanks so much for taking a look

Comment: is the second parameter for stats.percentileofscore correct? According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) it should be a float or int not Timestamp

Comment: That is what I thought. My main question was is there some method like this one to use with timestamps

Comment: I do not know of such a method, but any one would transform the timestamps to ordinal values for comparison which you can do yourself.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the Timestamps into units that `percentileofscore` can understand.  Also, `pd.DataFrame.notnull()` returns a boolean list that you may use to filter your `DataFrame`, it does not return the filtered list, so I've updated that for you.  Here is a working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "student": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "attempts": [14, 2, 5, 16],
    "time_0001": [
        "9/3/2019  12:32:32 AM",
        "9/3/2019  9:37:14 PM",
        "",
        "9/5/2019  8:58:14 PM"
    ]
})

student2Info = [14, 4, pd.Timestamp('2019-09-04 00:26:36')]
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time_0001'], errors='coerce')
perc1_first = stats.percentileofscore(data[data['time'].notnull()].time.transform(pd.Timestamp.toordinal), student2Info[2].toordinal(), 'rank')
print(perc1_first)  #-> 66.66666666666667
```

Comment: When I incorporated this method, I got the error `ValueError: NaTType does not support toordinal`

Comment: Just added in an additional if to use this method. Thanks!